# Why exponential distribution to model a queue?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

I am studying the queing models and I have a doubt.

Why to model intrerarrival times between two clients is used the exponential distribution?
I know that this distribution has the memory less property that make interarrival times independent. But why we cannot used independent gaussians distribution to model them?

What gives more the memory less property respect to the independence of times?
Could someone explain it without formulas just with words?

Thanks

Comment: It assumes that the number of arrivals in time $\lambda t$ follow a poisson process. Then the inter-arrival time will be exponential. Any text book on queueing or probability will cover the details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not the reverse? if the intearrival times is exponential then the number of arrival is poisson but Iam not sure that the reverse is true

Comment: Anyway my doubt is why the exponential distribution is used to model these kind of time events? Which is the property given by the memoryless property that should hold also in reality?

Comment: The independent arrival times of the poisson process (you only know the average arrival rate) creates the memoryless property. You may be right that exponential inter-arrival times implies poisson arrivals, but modelling the arrival process rather than the inter-arrival times seems a more logical argument.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you are right it is more logical with the Poisson. Anyway I am not able to understand intuitively the meaning of the memoryless property. Usually to explain it they write: "probabilities are not influenced by the past of the process" but this is not true also taking independent random variables with any kind of distribution?

Comment: You may think of the memoryless property in this way: Given that you have waited for a time $t$ and the next event has not arrive yet, the distribution of the arrival time is the same no matter how large the $t$ is - $1$ second, $1$ minute or $1$ year. E.g. if you use $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ to model, and given that the event has not arrived at $t = 0.9$, then you know that it will arrive in the next $0.1$ interval, and the truncated distribution $T|T > t$ is different than the original distribution of $T$. Only exponential have this property for continuous distribution.

Comment: It does not remember how long you have waited - no matter how long you have waited, the distribution of the next arrival is the same. The longer you waited does not make the next event more likely to arrive in the next moment.